# Sumif with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba, criteria, sumifs

I want to manage stocks I am purchasing. I have a ledgers table where I store TransactionDate, Stock, Ticker, Qty, Price, BrokeFee and some other data. I also have a StockHistory table where I pull the daily open, close, high, low and volume using the stockhistory feature which is built into Excel (via VBA).

In the StockHistory table I am trying to lookup the Ticker in the StockHistory table and do a Sumif where I want the total for a particular ticker (or stock) as of that particular date.

Working cell formula where column C is the Ticker in StockHistory Table and column A is the Date.

```
=SUMIFS(U:U,S:S,C7,Q:Q,"<=" & A7)
```

The following in VBA appears to be ignoring the Date Criteria and giving the overall grand total before and after the specified date.

```vb
Ticker = Cells(LastRowD, 3).Value
DateCheck = Cells(LastRowD, 1).Value
Qty = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("U:U"), _
  Range("S:S"), "=" & Ticker, Range("A:A"), "<=" & Range("A" & LastRowD))
```

Seen similar problems but none where one criteria works and another is ignored (but completes without errors).

Note: I have these two tables on separate sheets but have copied the Ledger over to the StockHistory tab whilst I troubleshoot to eliminate issues with referencing different worksheets.

Comment: What does `Debug.Print VarType(DateCheck)` return in the Immediate Window?

Comment: That returns 7. You did however make me think about the date and I do believe that is part of the problem. I am in Australia so our date format is dd/mm/yyyy and that is how I have the date formatted in both tables (and have verified). I have expanded the date range and any date that has a day higher than 12 is returning 0 and others are a mix of correct / incorrect. See this image

Comment: Ok it appears it was an issue with the date but try as I did I couldn't get it to work cleanly. I have however managed to get it to work without any error in calculation. The way I have done this is by adding an extra column to each table for the date in numerical format (ie. 23/2/21 = 44250) and then using those columns to verify the dates instead of the dates column. As stated feel the issue is because in Australia our date format is different to the USA and other regions. It appears to me (and I recall something similar from years ago in MS Access VBA) that VBA has issues with this format.

Comment: Any suggestion on how I can go back to using the dates column so I don't need this extra column?

Comment: If the dates are "real dates" (i.e. if you format the cell as `General` it will show the five digit number), then try using the `.Value2` property of the Range object instead to the default `.Value` property as you are now, when referring to dates on the worksheet.  (*Since you don't provide an example of data that demonstrates your problem, and which can be pasted into my worksheet, I cannot reproduce your problem to be certain*).  Read the MS documentation for the difference.

Comment: If the dates are not real dates, or have been converted incorrectly, you must also return to your method of entering your data and correct that, so that dates are properly imported and converted.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Ron, Using value2 worked. I tried another option very late last night that also worked but wasn't happy with it by using Int(cbdl(.....)). Not sure why this happens with dates. Cells are definitely date format in dd/mm/yyyy format as is my windows regional settings. As stated I recall having a similar issue years ago in MS Access. It appears to only occur sometimes with dates and in my current project all other code referencing dates works as intended. Some even on this same column that has this issue. Fair bit on google when you search directly (eg. australian dates vba) for it but for now its working so just going to leave it at that.
Thanks again Ron

Some screenshots
[Spreadsheet VBA Screenshot](https://postimg.cc/wRDJVzPT)
Spreadsheet Version 1. [Invalid totals](https://postimg.cc/Tp95YtvS), [High day numbers return '0'](https://postimg.cc/VdDWvjx7)
Working version. All 3 working versions return the same output. [Sample](https://postimg.cc/dLtGbhhG), [High Day sample working](https://postimg.cc/94G4R24W)

```
For LastRowD = LastRowD To LastRowB
    Ticker = Cells(LastRowD, 3).Value
    Qty = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("U:U"), Range("S:S"), "=" & Ticker, Range("Q:Q"), "<=" & Range("A" & LastRowD).Value2)
    Cells(LastRowD, 4) = Qty
    Cells(LastRowD, 5) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Product(Qty, Cells(LastRowD, 7))
Next LastRowD
```